# unable to get the debug log of a site guest user

Tags: force.com-sites, debug-logs

I am trying to track log of the site guest user. So I have created a debug log for the guest user. In order to spot which one is the guest user, I go to the site setting > public access setting > view users. And I am pretty sure I have created debug log track for that user.

However, when I operating on the site web pages as a guest user, it doesn't generate any debug log. I am quite confused why was that.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by adding a browser cookie. See the [release notes here](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter17/release-notes/rn_forcecom_debugging_guest_user.htm)

Salesforce does not debug the guest site user by default because they can generate a lot of debug logs.